# Moving Temp folder location

Tags: windows-7

My C drive is a small SSD that I don't want to wear out or fill with unnecessary  stuff. Is there any harm in moving the temp folder to another drive? I am under the impression that Windows will not need to look for files here, for example, in the case of uninstalls...

Is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, most programs will expect files in %TMP% or %TEMP% to be removed, unless they're locked, so I would say 99.9% No, unless you have an extremely badly designed program that writes permanent files to the temporary folder. See, that's why it's called the 'temporary' folder. You store **temporary** files in the **temporary** folder, and permanent (aka uninstall, program) files in other locations.

Answer (score 1):

You can move TEMP and TMP by editing the User System Variables.

[Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978682.aspx) is a TechNet article explaining the value in the registry, also covers how to change the variable.

There is no harm in moving the location using this method.  Some applications will cache installation files here.  For example Microsoft Office caches files in the temp directory.  If you need to uninstall, and the cached files cannot be found, there are ways around this issue.