# Can I remove all existing files in my temp folder immediately upon re-boot?

Tags: windows-xp, filesystems

Can I remove all existing files in my 'temp' folder immediately upon re-boot? Or are some of them important?

My belief is that one can remove any temporary files older than a day, but I am not sure.

System: Windows XP SP3

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/148279/moving-temp-folder-location (not about deleting temp files, but moving the folder - pretty much the same thing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temp files are OK being deleted as long as they aren't in use.  Programs can't expect that any files they drop into temp will be there after the program closes/releases the lock it has on the file(s).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no authoritative answer to this question.  The `%TEMP%` directory is just a directory like any other.  Any program can write files there for any reason.  It's possible that some program out there writes files to `%TEMP%`, and then expects them to stick around.  Granted, this would be poor behavior, but it's not impossible.

The only way to know if this is safe on *your system* is to try it and see what happens.  There are certain files on my system that I will probably never delete, because I don't want to take any chances.  You also need to ask yourself how much disk space you are really going to re-gain by doing this.

Personally I would start by looking at the file size and the "last modified" time.  If you see some really big files that haven't been touched in a while, then you might want to take a chance and delete them.

Answer (score 0):

Temp = temporary = not system related or needed across reboots, so yes you can delete them upon reboot.